# Proving that $E_g(x)=E_f(x)^2$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Denote the exponential generating function $f:\mathbb{N}\to K$ by $E_f(x)$, where $K$ stands for a field of characteristic $0$ such as $\mathbb{C}$ with some indeterminates adjoined)

Let $f(n)=1\times3\times\cdots\times(2n-1),g(n)=2^n\times n!$.

Can someone show me how can $E_g(x)$ be identical to $E_f(x)^2$?  In another words, how is $E_g(x)=e_f(x)^2$?

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's put it in this way,

$$\because1\times3\times\cdots\times(2n-1)=\dfrac{2n!}{2^n\times n!}$$
\begin{align*}
\therefore E_f(x)&=\sum_{n\geq0}\dfrac{x^n}{2^n}{2n\choose n}\\ \\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{-2x+1}}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\therefore E_f(x)^2&=\frac1{-2x+1}
\\ \\
&=\sum_{n\geq0}2^n\times x^n
\\ \\
&=\sum_{n\geq0}(2^n\times n!)\times\frac{x^n}{n!}
\\ \\
&=E_g(x)\ \ \square
\end{align*}

Comment: @Leeuwen Thanks for the corrections! Typing in $\LaTeX$ from paper isn't exactly fun